# Number of transactions in a block

Tags: transactions, blocks

Could someone kindly explain the reason behind the existence of **1189** transactions within block #**17873752** in the Ethereum network?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the surge in transaction count is attributed to the presence of a transfer bot. As illustrated in the image below, numerous dummy addresses are transferring ETH to 0x67655E8FCd903f75aceB82bB3f782687CE985d35, resulting in an accumulation of nearly 100k transactions at that address.

[image]